# Why are certain main menu features not found in the Shortcut mapper settings of Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, I want to add a shortcut for Edit > Line Operations > Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines, but it doesn’t show up in the Shortcut mapper settings, even though I’ve already added one for Edit > Line Operations > Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending. Why is that?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to get around that issue, just record selecting the `Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines` option from the menu by itself in a macro, then assign a shortcut to that recorded macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have already found answer, but the menu is available in shortcut mapper. You can quickly find it by typing, say, "consecutive" in the filter box at the lower side of the mapper dialog box.
[image: Screen-shot]

PS. It is quite possible that it might not be available 3 months ago when you asked the question and that Notepad++ might have added it in the meanwhile. I could find it in version 7.9 (64 bit).

Comment: Seems that they've fixed this in the latest version. Thanks for the heads up.